# How get the *original* cmd.exe console window title in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

As soon as PowerShell start run in a cmd.exe window the title of the window is changed to "Windows PowerShell"; however, the original title is stored in some place, because when PowerShell terminates, the original window title is recovered.

I spent some time reviewing the related documentation, but most examples show how get the *current* window title or *change it* using `$host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle`, but there is not a single example on getting the *original* cmd.exe window title (perhaps I just don't know what terms include in this search).

Is there any way to get the original console window title before PowerShell start run?

Comment: When I launch powershell 5.1 here I can see previous title: `title test & powershell -c "$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle"` prints `Administrator:  test  - powershell  -c "$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle"`

Comment: @wOxxOm: not here; the same line show `Windows Powershell`. Tested in two computers: Win 8.1 64-bits with PowerShell 3.0 and Win 8.1 32-bits with PowerShell 4.0. Please, don't reply that the solution to this problem is update the installed PS version to 5.1! **`:(`**

Comment: Not sure if this is of help, but there are a couple of examples to prevent PS from changing the title. Call the PS script using "Start". http://superuser.com/questions/822014/prevent-powershell-from-changing-title-of-command-window    Then read that title - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/05/22/get-windowtitle-ps1/

Comment: As for `the original title is stored in some place` it's apparently maintained by `conhost.exe` in its internal undocumented depths.

Answer (score 0):

Use next code snippet to get the original `cmd` console window title:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_myTitleTail= - %~0"
for /F "tokens=1,2,8,* delims=," %%G in ('
  tasklist /V /fo:csv ^| findstr /I /C:"%_myTitleTail%"
                                        ') do (
    set "_myTitleBatch=%%~J"
    set "_myCmdPIDno=%%~H"
)
call set "_myCmdTitle=%%_myTitleBatch:%_myTitleTail%=%%"
echo _myCmdPIDno=%_myCmdPIDno%
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo _myCmdTitle=!_myCmdTitle!
  rem powershell -NoExit -Command $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle='"!_myCmdTitle!"'
ENDLOCAL
```

Unfortunately, the `powershell -NoExit -Command $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle='"!_myCmdTitle!"'` (commented up in above code snippet) workaround works only for simple titles not containing `powershell` sensitive characters like apostrophes, double quotes etc.
For instance, next combination works with uncommented `powershell` line:

```
==> title some forgotten string
==> 39256629.bat
```

On the other hand, I didn't find proper escaping in case similar to [this (BTW, your current question inspired  my answer there)](https://superuser.com/a/1119780/376602)

```
==> TITLE ...but my title is complex, that's why I can't find proper escaping!!!
==> 39256629.bat
```

Powershell runs but keeps complaining for unexpected tokens tied to `...` dots
 or `'` apostrophes for different escaping attempts…

Comment: I guess a possible workaround for the special characters would be to echo the title to a temporary file and pass the path to powershell.