# Window title from start command change

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using the command start to launch a process from a cmd script, I want to identify this process by its window title

```
start "Calculation" %calculation%
```

With %calculation% a link to a .cmd

The problem is that the window opened by this command is not named "Calculation". It's named with "Calculaltion" with the command launched by the window.

How can i change that to keep only "Calculation" as window title ?

Comment: Please check (possibly helpful) http://superuser.com/a/1119780/376602 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/39262832/3439404

Answer (score 1):

You can either put the `title` command in the .cmd file, or use it on the command line just before you run the .cmd file:

```
start cmd /c "title Calculation & %calculation%"
```

Comment: When i use your command, the cmd name is 'Administrator : Calculation'. Is there a way to have only 'Calculation' ?

Comment: Yes, by not running as administrator. 'Administrator' is automatically added at the start of the title to remind you that you are running as a privileged user capable of causing irreparable damage to the system. You can try replacing `start` with `runas /trustlevel:0x20000`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why, when i search with "Administrator: Calculation", it doesn't work ? I need to copy/paste the title of the window. Same number of spaces but maybe spaces are not spaces ?

Comment: @VincentROSSIGNOL  you can copy it from output of `tasklist /v | find "cmd"`